# Regex pattern for String with multiple leading and trailing ones and zeroes

Tags: java, regex

I have a search String which contains the format below:

**Search String**

```
    111651311
    111651303
    4111650024
    4360280062
    20167400
```

It needs to be matched with sequence of numbers below

```
001111651311000
001111651303000
054111650024000
054360280062000
201674000000000
```

Please note the search strings have been added with additional numbers either on each sides.
I have tried the regex below in java to match the search strings but it only works for some.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9])\1*"+c4MIDVal+"([0-9])\1*");
```

Any advice ?

## Update

Added the code I used below might provide some clarity on what am trying to do

Code Snippet

```
public void compare(String fileNameAdded, String fileNameToBeAdded){
        
        List<String> midListAdded = readMID.readMIDAdded(fileNameAdded);
        
        HashMap<String, String> midPairsToBeAdded = readMID.readMIDToBeAdded(fileNameToBeAdded);
        List <String []> midCaptured = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        
        
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: midPairsToBeAdded.entrySet()){
            
            String c4StoreKey = entry.getKey();
            String c4MIDVal = entry.getValue();
            
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]?)\\1*"+c4MIDVal+"([0-9]?)\\2*");
                        
            for (String mid : midListAdded){
                
                Matcher match = pattern.matcher(mid);
//              logger.info("Match Configured MID :: "+ mid+ " with Pattern "+"\\*"+match.toString()+"\\*");
                
                if (match.find()){
                    
                    midCaptured.add(new String []{ c4StoreKey +"-"+c4MIDVal, mid});
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        logger.info(midCaptured.size()+ " List of Configured MIDs ");
        for (String [] entry: midCaptured){
            
            logger.info(entry[0]+ "- "+entry[1]  );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't `indexOf` be sufficient ?

Comment: or `contains`. K.I.S.S.

Comment: i have included my code please check

Answer (score 2):

You need to refer the second capturing group in the second part and also you need to make both the patterns inside the capturing group as optional.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]?)\\1*"+c4MIDVal+"([0-9]?)\\2*");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lB9oU6/1)

Comment: Also, the dynamic part should be quoted: `Pattern.quote(c4MIDVal)`. Probably not needed, since it's just numbers, but still a good idea.

Comment: hi avinash, thanks for the reply. tried your suggestion but still have the number of results. It can match this but not these sequence 054111650024000.

Comment: @dimas what's the c4MIDVal value?

Comment: c4MIDVal is the search string

Comment: what's the value for this?

Comment: there are many possible values and they're labeled as Search String. please check my update

Comment: if it's a list of search strings, then you need to join them with `|` as delimiter. Then pass that joined string as value of `c4MIDVal` variable.

Comment: actually its just one value at a time so my logic loops through a list gets the search string example 111651311 then find the match from the list of sequence numbers by comparing each one

Comment: added my code to clarify what i mean on previous statement

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem by using the `String.contains()` method?

```
"001111651311000".contains("111651311"); // true
"201674000000000".contains("111651311"); // false
```

Comment: it won't return the matched string.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It is the String which you are comparing?